# Share a subscription if observable not done

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have an angular application that should sync some data with the server on some conditions (some triggers in software or when user request). So i have a function like this:

```
    ...

    public createSyncObservable(): Observable<any> {
        return this.retriveDataFromStorage().pipe(
            switchMap(
                (data) => forkJoin(this.api.sendData1(data.data1),this.api.sendData2(data.data2),this.api.sendData3(data.data3))
            ),
            switchMap(
                (data) => this.api.getDataFromServer()
            ),
            switchMap(
                (data) => this.updateLocal(data)
            )
        )
    }
```

The behaviour I want is:

- If user (or some trigger) request the sync and it is already happening, I should not do it again, just wait for the current sync to end and return the same observable (shared).
- If last sync already finished, it should start again (create a new observable).

My best solution for now is to do something like this (untested code):

```
    ...
    public syncData(): Observable<any> {
        if (this.observable_complete) {
            this.observable_complete = false;
            this.syncObservable$ = this.createSyncObservable().pipe(share())
            this.syncObservable$.subscribe(
                (data) => {this.observable_complete = true}
            ) 
        }
        return this.syncObservable$;
    }
```

Is this the way to go? Maybe I am missing some RxJS operator that would help me in this case? This solution just seems a bit hacky...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If calling `this.createSyncObservable()` doesn't do any actual work but only subscribing to the observable it returns does you only need to call the function once. You could then simply do:

```
public syncData$ = this.createSyncObservable().pipe(share());
```

`share` will unsubscribe from its source if there are no subscribers left (i.e. when `this.createSyncObservable()` completed). So a subscriber to `this.syncData$` will trigger a subscribe to the observable returned from `this.createSyncObservable()` if it completed.

```ts
// The first subscribe will trigger a subscribe to createSyncObservable()
syncData$.subscribe()
// A second subscribe while the first hasn't completed won't trigger a subscribe
// to createSyncObservable() but instead just wait for its response
syncData$.subscribe()

// After some time ...
// Another subscribe after createSyncObservable() completed will trigger another 
// subscribe to createSyncObservable()
syncData$.subscribe()
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-44qzaj?file=index.ts

Comment: This is indeed the best way to go, in my opinion.
Just ensure that `createSyncObservable` completes and you are all set

Comment: You are indeed right. I misunderstood how the share pipe works, but there is no need to check if it has returned and create another observable since the same one will trigger with a new subscribe. @Guilhermevrs, thanks, i'll make sure the syncObservable always completes, maybe add a timeout pipe to be sure...

Answer (score 0):

You should try with the takeWhile/skipWhile operator:

This is just an example, but I hope you find it usefull.

```
private isResourceFree = true;

public createSyncObservable(): Observable<any> {

        return of(isResourceFree).pipe(
            takeWhile(val => val),
            tap(_ => this.isResourceFree = false),
            switchMap(_ => this.retriveDataFromStorage()),
            switchMap(
                (data) => forkJoin(this.api.sendData1(data.data1),this.api.sendData2(data.data2),this.api.sendData3(data.data3))
            ),
            switchMap(
                (data) => this.api.getDataFromServer()
            ),
            switchMap(
                (data) => this.updateLocal(data)
            ),
            tap(_ => this.isResourceFree = true)
        )
    }
```